# How to find 2 largest values from group of rows in multiple columns in Python and also show its row and column index at output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, max

I am new to python. I want to find the largest values from all the columns for repetitive row elements (i.e. 5 to 101), and also show its row and column index label in output.The largest values should be absolute. (Irrespective of + or - sign) The group of row indexes will keep on repeating for 'n'number of times. For every 'nth' group of row index, I want 'n' largest values and their index positions for each group.

In my dataset, Rows index 5,10,12,101, repeates 3 times in same sequence(For FX, FY and FZ). So my output must show 2 largest values for each group FX,FY,FZ. If my row index(5,10,12,101) repeats 'n' times in same sequence, Output must display 'n' Max. values for FX,FY, and FZ.

Dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'E_at_0': [43, -53, 45, -17, 19, 11, 32, 36, 19, 11, 32, 36], 
              'E_at_10': [-47, 47, 46, -18, 16, 12, 34, -52, 16, 12, 34, -71], 
              'E_at_20': [56, 43, -41, 29, 14, 13, 33, 43, 14, 13, 33, 43], 
              'E_at_30': [-46, 16, -40, -11, 15, 33, -39, -22, 15, 63, -39, -22]}, index=[5, 10, 12, 101, 5, 10, 12, 101, 5, 10, 12, 101])
```

```
df = pd.read_csv ('Allgroups.csv')

df = df.set_index('Ele_Num')
a = int(input("Enter total number of groups: "))

def f(x):
    x1 = x.abs().stack()
    x2 = x.stack()
    x = x2.iloc[np.argsort(-x1)].head(2)
    return x

groups = (df.index == 5).cumsum()
df1 = df.groupby(groups).apply(f).reset_index(level=[1,2])
df1.columns = ['Ele_Num','Column','Values']

print (df1)

df1.to_csv('Group_Output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=True)

for i in range (1,a+1):

    print (df1.loc[i])
```

Expected Results:

```
2 Largest Values from FX:
   Element No   Column  Values
1           5  E_at_20      56
1          10  E_at_0      -53

2 Largest Values from FY:
    Element No   Column  Values
2          101  E_at_10     -52
2          101  E_at_20      43

2 Largest Values from FZ:
   Element No   Column  Values
3         101   E_at_10      71
3          10   E_at_30     -63
```

Actual Results:

```
   Element No   Column  Values
1           5  E_at_20      56
1          10   E_at_0     -53
2         101  E_at_10     -71
2          10  E_at_30      63
```

```
   Element No   Column  Values
1           5  E_at_20      56
1          10   E_at_0     -53

   Element No   Column  Values
2         101  E_at_10     -71
2          10  E_at_30      63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only `3` or few groups I suggest create dictionary for mapping:

```
d = {1:'FX', 2:'FY', 3:'FZ'}

for i in range (1,a+1):
    print (d[i]) 
    print (f'{a} Largest Values from {d[i]}')
    print (df1.loc[i])
```

Comment: Thanks. In addition, If you could help me eliminating the duplicates. Eg. for above data set, group 2 and group 3, ```Element No. 101 E_at_10``` is repeated. In 2 groups if Element No. is same, Output must show only 1 instance for group with largest **Value**. ie. for group 3. Value **-71**

Comment: @Akshay K. Is possible create new question?

Comment: Ok. Posted a new one